# override snowflake hook in airflow

Tags: airflow

I have a question about how is the best practices to overwrite a hook.

The project (inherited) clone the hook code (go to airflow github project, copy the hook, paste in the project a create custom operators with this copied hook). I want to change this method to work with the hooks that airfow have.
The problem is that how the company works with the credentials. The Airflow hooks  run with the connection page: [image]

But the company have a repository where all the credentials are stored so I thought to overwrite the init class like this:

```
from airflow.contrib.hooks.snowflake_hook import SnowflakeHook

class SnowflakeHook(SnowflakeHook):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        env = VariableManagement()
        self.user = env.GetVariable('user')
        self.password = env.GetVariable('pass')
```

Is this a correct way to work? can I do better solution?

Thanks

Comment: you can do this. Don't use the same name for the class. Also why are you importing from contrib rather than providers?

Comment: Im using 1.10.12. I dont know why with pip install dont appear in provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to implement a custom [secrets backend](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/secrets-backend/index.html#roll-your-own-secrets-backend).

Sure you can subclass the hook.  But now you can't use it with existing operators unless you override them too.  And you would have to do this for every such hook you want to use.

Instead, you can use your company's creds store as a backend for airflow's connection system.

Then you should be able to avoid having to subclass every hook that you use.

The cleanest solution will be to update your creds repository to store creds in [airflow's URI format](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html?highlight=connections#connection-uri-format).

But if that's not possible for you, it will still be pretty straigthforward.